# How to customize a form with php?

Tags: forms

I want to put my form in a table. After some searches I've found this code.

```
 $form['city'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select', 
    '#title' => $list_titles['city'], 
    '#options' => $list_cities,
    '#prefix' => '<table height= \'30\' width=\'80%\'><tr><td width=\'100\'>', 
    '#suffix' => '</td>', '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value'=> $node->city
    );  
  $form['adr'] = array('#type' => 'textfield', '#title' => $list_titles['adr'], '#required' => TRUE, 
    '#prefix' => '<td>', 
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr></table>',
    '#default_value'=> $node->adr
    );
```

Where do I put this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use #prefix and #suffix to wrap the form elements in a table.  Here's an example:

```
function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {

        $form['field1'] = array(
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('My Field'),
                '#prefix' => '<table><tr><td>',
                '#suffix' => '</td>',
        );

        $form['submit'] = array (
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => t('Submit'),
                '#prefix' => '<td>',
                '#suffix' => '</td></tr></table>',
        );

return $form;

}
```

Comment: so i must create a custom module ?

Comment: Yes, you should create a custom module.

Comment: it's not working. any idea of what i could have done wrong?

Comment: what i forgot to mention is that this form is actually the form for node/add (create content)

Comment: So it is a node form?

Comment: yes, it is. the user is supposed to fill in these "rows" in a table in order to create something like a log, where the fields should correspond to those in the node form.

Comment: In that case, you need to declare your node type first, with hook_node_info(), then, your node form function should look like this: function mymodule_mynode_form ($node, &$form_state)...